# ITextSharp not render text box, radio button when convert html to pdf in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am working with Asp.net MVC and using ITextSharp DLL version 5.5.13 to create PDF from HTML view page .

I have a HTML page with label, image, text box, radio button, check-box, drop down and calendar control. It renders
well on web page, but when I convert this HTML file to PDF, it does not display any field except label and image.

I am using the below code to generate PDF where GridHtml parameter holds the html of my web page.

```
public FileResult Export(string GridHtml)
    {
    using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
    }
    }
```

Can someone please suggest if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks

Comment: iText 5.5.13 might look like a recent version, but it's actually a *maintenance release* of a version that is being phased out. The most recent version is iText 7. Note that we don't call it iTextSharp anymore. It's iText for .NET. This being said: form elements have never been supported in the old XML Worker (and they never will). There is (limited) support for form fields in iText 7 + pdfHTML. See the [FAQ](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/can-i-convert-html-form-pdf).

Comment: When I read that you need a calendar control, I am pretty sure that this isn't supported (yet) because that's something very specific for HTML (I haven't seen it in many PDF's, if any). Your chances at getting that functionality supported in iText 5 (the version you're using) are close to zero. However, if you move to iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on, there is a chance that you can put it on the roadmap if you're a paying customer.